# Synchronized task queue in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, queue

I have a multithreaded environment with special tasks that need to be called synchronously (one after another).

I made a simple static class called `SynchronizedWorker` containing a `Queue` of delegates and locks. It contains a `ProcessTask` method that puts a new task in the queue and waits until the task is done.

It also contains `ProcessTasks` private method that processes all the tasks on a separate thread. If it is running when new task arrives, the task is just put on queue and we wait.

To notify a caller that his particular task is done, a `ManualResetEvent` instance is created for the task. However, I am not sure if this is a "good" solution since there can be possibly hundreths of such tasks queued and maybe one lock would suffice:

```
public static class SynchronizedWorker
{
    private static Queue<KeyValuePair<Action, ManualResetEvent>> tasks = new Queue<KeyValuePair<Action, ManualResetEvent>>();
    private static bool isProcessingTasks = false;
    private static object syncRoot = new object();

    public static void ProcessTask(Action task)
    {
        ManualResetEvent waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        bool startProcessing;

        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            tasks.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<Action, ManualResetEvent>(task, waitHandle));

            // check if task processing need to start over
            startProcessing = (isProcessingTasks == false);

            isProcessingTasks = true;
        }

        if (startProcessing)
        {
            // start task processing
            Task.Factory.StartNew(ProcessTasks);
        }

        // wait until our task is done
        waitHandle.WaitOne();
    }

    private static void ProcessTasks()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Action task;
            ManualResetEvent waitHandle;

            lock (syncRoot)
            {
                if (tasks.Count == 0)
                {
                    // all done
                    isProcessingTasks = false;

                    break;
                }

                var pair = tasks.Dequeue();

                task = pair.Key;
                waitHandle = pair.Value;
            }

            // perform the task
            task();

            // signal that we are done
            waitHandle.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the idea that ProcessWorker would be called from many different threads?

Comment: @jaket Exactly. Like when multiple threads are doing I/O operations on disk - it is synchronized on some level. I need something like this a special tasks that used shared resource and need to run synchronously while the callers need not to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single `AutoResetEvent` was sufficient:

```
public static class SynchronizedWorker
{
    private static AutoResetEvent waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    public static void ProcessTask(Action task)
    {
        if (waitHandle.WaitOne())
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew((() =>
            {
                // process task
                task();

                // signal that we are done
                waitHandle.Set();
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that is 100% correct because

1. your wait handle starts locked and nobody uses Set(). Should be true
2. your WaitOne() is still executed in the main thread.

Nr. 2 means that the current thread will be blocked and it won't be done in a "task" way at all. Maybe that is exactly what you are looking for, but for starting "some" task and continuing, but only wanting those task to start if some other finished, it's not enough.